# c++ \" escape sequence for purpose of including quotes inside system() function

Tags: c++, escaping, system, sequence, cd

I have a question about using the \" escape sequence. [image] So my first question would be how would I get this cmd statement to work?

cd "c:\users\aegis\" $T sup.cmd

I am also aware of the ability to use & and && inside of the system function, but could someone provide me with a better understanding of how this would work?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    system("start c:\\users\\aegis\\sup.cmd");
```

The following code works to open the cmd, but I want to have more control. I am also currently pending on a question waiting for someone to explain to me thorougly how systemexecute() systemexecuteEx() and createprocess() work. I am fairly new to c++ so I feel as though createprocess and systemexecute() may be too far in depth for me.

Comment: You're likely better of looking into `ShellExecute`(for windows only). The `system` call is fairly expensive and involves all kinds of stuff behind the scenes, even just doing `system("pause");` to wait for a key takes an eternity, cpu-cycle wise. `ShellExecute` allows you to specify command line parameters for your spawned program. There's a billion examples out there of its use. MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the " character with \, then your system() call would look like this:

```
system("start \"c:\\users\\aegis\\sup.cmd\"");
```